# XML substitution nor working in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, iis-7, azure-pipelines

I have two deploy pipelines in Azure DevOps that are deploying to IIS

1. a Website, That deploys to the server, has XML Substitution turned on and the connection and app strings are updated. This is Working fine.
2. a Web Application configured as a subfolder of the previous website. It Deploys to the server, has XML substitution turned on, however, Connection strings are not updated.

The log for the web application reports that XML Substitution has been applied successfully. But it has not actually been applied.

How can I Debug and solve this? Is this a known limitation to Web Applications? (which can inherit from the parent web.config)

I would provide more info, but I simply cannot find anymore.

Comment: You can try to set variable `system.debug` to `true` and rerun the release. Debug logs reveals whether the substitution happened for the required variables. Here are some cases with similar issue,you can refer to these solution([case1](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/316336/xml-variable-substitution-not-working.html),[case2](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/191530/xml-variable-substitution-not-working-for-some-var.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that solve the similar issue,you can use as a reference.

In the contributor's case, he changed the following two to get it to work:

1.Configuration type - The template for IIS website deployment defaults the Configuration type to "`IIS Website`". He changed this to "`IIS Web Application`".

2.Package or Folder (probably the fix) - The IIS Web App Deploy task's Package or Folder option he had originally set to the artifact's drop folder's parent folder. That sentence was probably confusing - this value was `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_my-project-name-ASP.NET-CI`. He changed this by browsing (the `...` button) down to the actual `/drop/my-project-name.zip file`.

For details,you can refer to the cases mentioned in comment.